# MySQL - Insert intro if exist update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have unknown keys and values to import to database from CSV.
My code is

```
while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'))
{
$data=array_map('addslashes',$data); // apply addslashes() to all values
$data=array_combine($csv_fields,$data); // csv fields assoc (key=>value)
$data=array_intersect_key($data,$tbl_fields); // discard redundant
$tbl_fields_str=implode("`,`",array_keys($data));
$tbl_vals_str=implode("','",array_values($data));
$q="INSERT INTO `cmid` (`cmid`,`$tbl_fields_str`) VALUES ('$cmidtrenutni','$tbl_vals_str') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (`$tbl_fields_str`) VALUES ('$tbl_vals_str')";
$conn->query($q); 
}
```

I need to insert and if exist, update.
I try this code above but doesnt work.
I find something like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
But this doesnt help in my way cause my table doesnt have defined fields. Keys and values are different on every input.
Any solution how to do this?

Comment: The ON DUPLICATE KEY requires a primary or unique index on the table, otherwise.  If you want to update a row if it already exists, that seems to imply that whatever column(s) you're checking are in fact unique, so I would suggest creating a unique index on the column(s).

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO `cmid` (`cmid`, `$tbl_fields_str`)
    VALUES ('$cmidtrenutni', '$tbl_vals_str')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (`$tbl_fields_str`) VALUES ('$tbl_vals_str');
```

The problem is the `UPDATE` part.  You need to split the values so it looks like:

```
INSERT INTO `cmid` (`cmid`, `$tbl_fields_str`)
    VALUES ('$cmidtrenutni', '$tbl_vals_str')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         col1 = newcol1val,
         col2 = newcol2val,
         . . .
```

The short-hand that you are using is not valid syntax.

Comment: Yes, but columns and values are unknow.

Comment: @r00t-err0r . . . You will need to fix the query to use proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To import from a csv file, take a look at the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://localhost/doc/mysql-docs/refman-5.5-en.html-chapter/sql-syntax.html#load-data) statement or the [mysqlimport](http://localhost/doc/mysql-docs/refman-5.5-en.html-chapter/programs.html#mysqlimport) utility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$q="INSERT INTO `cmid` (`cmid`,`$tbl_fields_str`) VALUES ('$cmidtrenutni','$tbl_vals_str') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cmid=cmid";
```

But I prefer using `INSERT IGNORE` for your problem:

```
$q="INSERT IGNORE INTO `cmid` (`cmid`,`$tbl_fields_str`) VALUES ('$cmidtrenutni','$tbl_vals_str')";
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have "unknown" columns in mysql DB. if you want to store pairs of key-value in a mysql table, you should have a table with two columns : one would be named "key" and the other one "value". Add an extra column "cmid" to group your pairs.

This table should have a primary index  on "cmid" and "key" columns.

Then you should insert values with a query like:

```
$sqlVals = "";
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
   $sqlVals .= "($cmidtrenutni, $key, $val),";
}
$sqlVals = substr($sqlVals, 0, -1); //remove last comma.

$query = "REPLACE INTO `myTable` (`cmid`, `key`,`value`) VALUES $sqlVals";
```